# Auto fill my custom form using facebook data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a form designed which takes input values. I want people to click the button "sign up as facebook" which takes in their facebook details and as a result fills my custom form with the appropriate values. i want it to be like this one. https://www.odesk.com/signup/create-account/id/Contractor_50dbed1edc1416.20352143

Please tell me how can this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill form using facebook data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124701/fill-form-using-facebook-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Registration Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) is what you are looking for. :)

**UPDATED**

In Case you want to have custom form. You would have to take permission from user and get his details. You can use following Code :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',status : true,xfbml  : true, cookie: true ,oauth  : true});


function login(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        // checks if user already authorized
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            FB.api('me?fields=id,name,email', function(user) {
                                     if(user != null) {
                                                                username  = user.name;
                                                                uid = user.id;
                                                                email = user.email;
                                                            }
                                });

                    } else {
        // If user is not authorized call FB.login for pop up window for authorization  , scope defines list of persmission requested with user
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse.accessToken) {    
                                            FB.api('me?fields=id,name,email', function(user) {
                                                    if(user != null) {
                                                                username  = user.name;
                                                                uid = user.id;
                                                                email = user.email;
                                                            }
                                                        }) 
                                                    } 
                                                }, {scope:'email'});
                    }

                });
    }
```

You call login() at the press of your button.

Comment: Yes but this is in the iframe. I want to use this info to fill my own custom made form like once authoruized the input values of my form should be fillep up

Comment: i ve updated the comment, pls check

Comment: im new to javascript as well . Could you tel me how could i call these values of email,firstname and last name in my <input> tag.?

Comment: In that case, you should start searching SO for help :). To replace the values of your tags: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5700542/1343690

Comment: Ok which functions do i need to call on my fb-button click?

Comment: I've written in the comment-> the login function- this will will check  whether the user has authorized the app or not, and save the details in the respective variables