# Sign Up Using Facebook Autofill my form

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to make my facebook signup button do what the odesk signup button does.

https://www.odesk.com/signup/create-account/id/Contractor_50dbed1edc1416.20352143

Note: I have design the form the button placed everything. What do i do next.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/14050599/1343690

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto fill my custom form using facebook data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050528/auto-fill-my-custom-form-using-facebook-data)